# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class BoardLocations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject A1;
    public class Coords
    {
        public Vector3 aOne = A1.transform.position;
    }
}
```

This is all in one script, attached to an empty game object. The error I get is "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'BoardLocations.A1'". The only way to make the error go away is to make the GameObject and Vector3 static, but doing that means I can't see the GameObject in the inspector, which I need to assign the GameObject. Placing the GameObject in the same class as the Vector3 yields the same results. How can I reference the GameObject in the class so the Vector3 can see it?

Answer (score 1):

your class coords is not having 'BoardLocations' reference. your code should be like
`public class Coords
{

```
public Vector3 aOne;

void Start()
{
    stackof se = new stackof();
    GameObject e = se.A1;
    aOne = e.transform.position;

}
}`
```